# How to read the specific data from an excel and write them in different column of the same worksheet.using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJTsx.png)[I want to copy the data under the column 'Row Labels'(A6) and write them under the column 'Incident'(F2) by overwriting the previous data in the same excel sheet] Please help me out.

Comment: `range("a6").copy range("f2")`? Edit: er that's vba. I don't know asp.net.

Comment: image link- http://i.stack.imgur.com/f1bKb.png

Comment: What have you tried? The two most typical methods of working with OpenXML (i.e. Office) files is either via the OpenXML SDK (available for C#) or use the `Office.Interop.Excel` namespace. The latter offers more functionality, but you need to have Excel installed where your code will be executed, which isn't always feasible. The first option seems better suited for your task.